# ¿Cómo mejorar una consulta en SQL usando la sentencia CASE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2017

Este es el resultado esperado
[image: Resultado esperado]

Y este es el resultado obtenido a partir de la siguiente consulta
[image: Resultado obtenido de la consulta]

Consulta SQL

```
WITH reporte as (
SELECT area,tipo_id,
    count(tipo_id) as colum1,
    count(tipo_id) as colum2,
    count(tipo_id) as colum3
    FROM app_accidente
where tipo_id in(1,2,3)
group by area,tipo_id
)
select  area,
Accidentes_Tipo_A=
case
when  tipo_id=1 then colum1
end,
Accidentes_Tipo_B=
case
when  tipo_id=2 then colum2
end,
Accidentes_Tipo_C=
case
when  tipo_id=3 then colum3
end
from reporte;
```

Para reemplazar los valores NULL por 0, intente usar la sentencia ISNULL(), de la siguiente manera; sin embargo no hubo cambio alguno en el resultado.

```
ISNULL(count(tipo_id),0) as colum1,
ISNULL(count(tipo_id),0)  as colum2,
ISNULL(count(tipo_id,0) as colum3
```

Para el TOTAL de cada columna no se me ocurre cómo podría implementar esa suma, no sé si se podria insertar un ALIAS TOTALES hasta abajo de la columna Area

**SOLUCIÓN**

```
with reporte as (SELECT area,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN tipo_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Accidentes_Tipo_A,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN tipo_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Accidentes_Tipo_B,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN tipo_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Accidentes_Tipo_C
    FROM app_accidente
    where tipo_id in(1,2,3)
group by area)
select area,Accidentes_Tipo_A,Accidentes_Tipo_B,Accidentes_Tipo_C
from reporte
union all
  Select 'TOTALES'
          , SUM(r.Accidentes_Tipo_A) AS A_ACCIDENTES_TIPO_A
          , SUM(r.Accidentes_Tipo_B) AS A_ACCIDENTES_TIPO_B
          , SUM(r.Accidentes_Tipo_C) AS A_ACCIDENTES_TIPO_C
FROM Reporte r;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de crear un escenario de prueba, pude comprobar que mi primera respuesta no causaba ninguna diferencia en el resultado original.

El código en esta edición, produce resultados similares a los esperados, pero no son idénticos porque quedan en un orden diferente y con una línea menos debido a que los totales del área 'Frios' se consolidan.

`Resultado obtenido:`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las modificaciones al código original consisten en producir un resultado intermedio, bien sea en una variable de tipo [Table](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) o en una tabla temporal. El resultado final se obtiene concatenando dos consultas que se hacen al resultado intermedio. [Ver Operador UNION](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

### Solución utilizando variable de tipo `Table`

En este ejemplo utilizo una variable de tipo Table porque el resultado del ejemplo contiene pocos registros, pero es importante tener en cuenta las [limitaciones de las variables de tipo Table](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Si el resultado esperado es superior a 100 registros, será mejor utilizar una tabla temporal, cuyo ejemplo encontrará más adelante.

```
--Declara una variable de tipo tabla para guardar de manera temporal
--el resultado porque se consultará 2 veces
declare @tabla table (
    Area varchar(20), 
    Tipo_A int, 
    Tipo_B int, 
    Tipo_C int
);

--Este bloque se mantiene igual
WITH reporte as (
SELECT area,tipo_id,
    count(tipo_id) as colum1,
    count(tipo_id) as colum2,
    count(tipo_id) as colum3
    FROM app_accidente
where tipo_id in(1,2,3)
group by area,tipo_id
)

-- Nuevo código, hace un Select para cambiar los valores null por cero
-- y lo inserta en la variable tabla
INSERT INTO @tabla
Select area, COALESCE(Tipo_A, 0), COALESCE(Tipo_B, 0), COALESCE(Tipo_C, 0) from 

-- Este bloque lo simplifiqué un poco sin cambiarle el sentido original
-- Además lo coloqué entre parentesis y le di un nombre para que
-- la consulta anterior pueda funcionar.
(select area,
    Tipo_A = case when tipo_id=1 then colum1 end,
    Tipo_B = case when tipo_id=2 then colum2 end,
    Tipo_C = case when tipo_id=3 then colum3 end
from reporte) as resultado

-- Obtiene el resultado final consultando la variable tabla
Select Area, 
       SUM(Tipo_A) as [Accidentes Tipo A], 
       SUM(Tipo_B) as [Accidentes Tipo B], 
       SUM(Tipo_C) as [Accidentes Tipo C] from @tabla GROUP BY Area
UNION 
Select 'TOTALES', SUM(Tipo_A), SUM(Tipo_B), SUM(Tipo_C) from @tabla
```

### Solución utilizando una tabla temporal

Cuando el resultado esperado supera las limitaciones de la variable tipo Table, esta es la opción recomendada.

```
-- A la tabla temporal le di el nombre #temptabla 
-- pero puede utilizar cualquier otro siempre que comience con #

-- Valida si la tabla temporal existe para eliminarla
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#temptabla') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #temptabla
    END
GO

--Este bloque se mantiene igual
WITH reporte as (
SELECT area,tipo_id,
    count(tipo_id) as colum1,
    count(tipo_id) as colum2,
    count(tipo_id) as colum3
    FROM app_accidente
where tipo_id in(1,2,3)
group by area,tipo_id
)

-- Nuevo código, hace un Select para cambiar los valores null por cero
-- y lo inserta en la tabla temporal
Select area, COALESCE(Tipo_A, 0) as Tipo_A, 
             COALESCE(Tipo_B, 0) as Tipo_B, 
             COALESCE(Tipo_C, 0) as Tipo_C INTO #temptabla from 

-- Este bloque lo simplifiqué un poco sin cambiarle el sentido original
-- Además lo coloqué entre parentesis y le di un nombre para que
-- la consulta anterior pueda funcionar.
(select area,
    Tipo_A = case when tipo_id=1 then colum1 end,
    Tipo_B = case when tipo_id=2 then colum2 end,
    Tipo_C = case when tipo_id=3 then colum3 end
from reporte) as resultado

-- Obtiene el resultado final consultando la tabla temporal
Select Area, 
       SUM(Tipo_A) as [Accidentes Tipo A], 
       SUM(Tipo_B) as [Accidentes Tipo B], 
       SUM(Tipo_C) as [Accidentes Tipo C] from #temptabla GROUP BY Area
UNION 
Select 'TOTALES', SUM(Tipo_A), SUM(Tipo_B), SUM(Tipo_C) from #temptabla
```

Answer (score 3):

Creo que la idea la tienes, pero no esta bien implementada, ya que debes contar dentro del `GROUP BY` por `area` (no por `area` y `tipo_id` y usar un `COUNT` condicional:

```
SELECT area,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN tipo_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Accidentes_Tipo_A,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN tipo_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Accidentes_Tipo_B,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN tipo_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Accidentes_Tipo_C
    FROM app_accidente
    where tipo_id in(1,2,3)
    group by area
```

Answer (score 1):

EL 0 de los case lo puedes obtener utilizando un else en el mismo.

La suma de totales, utilizando union all para obtener una nueva lectura.

```
;with reporte as (
    SELECT area,tipo_id,
        count(tipo_id) as colum1,
        count(tipo_id) as colum2,
        count(tipo_id) as colum3
        FROM app_accidente
    where tipo_id in(1,2,3)
    group by area,tipo_id
    )
select    area 
        , case when tipo_id = 1 then colum1
                    else 0
          end As Accidentes_Tipo_A
        , case when tipo_id = 2 then colum2
                    else 0
          end As Accidentes_Tipo_B
        , case when tipo_id = 3 then colum3
                    else 0
          end As Accidentes_Tipo_C
       from reporte
union all
    Select 'TOTALES'
          , SUM(R.Colum1) AS A_ACCIDENTES_TIPO_A
          , SUM(R.colum2) AS A_ACCIDENTES_TIPO_B
          , SUM(R.colum3) AS A_ACCIDENTES_TIPO_C
FROM Reporte r;
```

[image: Resultado]

[Union All](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/07/union-vs-union-all/)